# How to share clipboard between windows PC and apple ecostystem (iOS, macOS)?

Tags: windows, macos

Was curious whether this was possible? 1Clipboard no longer is authorised by google so doesn't work. Would be grateful for any help.

Answer (score -1):

You need a third-party product for sharing the mouse between computers.

You could try
[ShareMouse](https://www.sharemouse.com/doc/clipboard/).
The free version supports two computers or monitors.
There are also
[alternatives to ShareMouse](https://alternativeto.net/software/sharemouse/).

As I haven't used such products, I can't recommend any from experience.

Comment: Would the learned downvoter share with us his method for sharing the clipboard across the network without a third-party products?